# Multiplexing CMOS Cameras

Tags: hardware, design

How is it possible to multiplex 9 CMOS Cameras with raspberry pi to generate 9 images at a time?

Comment: Multiplexing.. inherently is NOT real-time. You will never get ALL the images at ONE TIME. You can cycles the data bus to each camera and download images one by one.. as fast as possible. This could be sub 100ms but it may well be sub 1000ms depending on the setup. And then the question is what is the BUS? Serial Data as in not USB but actual old school serial? Otherwise forget it. Just ust 8 USB cameras. That way you can get all 9 at the same time! Good luck, please poest an answer when you done!

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant I have to switch among the 9 cameras and store one image per camera. The 9 cameras must be simply multiplexed and the 9 photos are taken one after the other. The cameras must stay on the same bus.

Comment: Great.. you can accomplish that using Serial / I2C (not USB) data transfer with any kind of multiplexer. You will have one bus to the multiplexer, from which all the other cameras will get connected to using a serial connection. You could get away with USB but it would require each time to reinitialise the device and OS's (LInux,Mac and Windows) don't like it when that happens allot.. trust me.. i tried with something else.. it just crashes too often.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was seeing some multiplexer like arducam and IVport. Are those a good option?

Comment: Can you show me a tutorial video on this?

Comment: One more thing. I am new to raspberry pi. So if you can tell me how do I switch from one camera to the other.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for multiple pictures all being taken at the same time - You may want to check this guy out.
http://www.instructables.com/id/Multiple-Raspberry-PI-3D-Scanner

While he is not multiplexing multiple cameras into one Pi, he is triggering multiple cameras each connected to a separate Pi simultaneously.

He started out with 48 cameras and as of the latest update he was up to 168 cameras all firing simultaneously for his full sized 3D scanner.